# how do I cancel Subscription in stripe inside react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am using react. I want to delete old subscription when user changes his subscription plan.

this is my code.

import {loadStripe, useStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js'

```
const loadCheckout = async (priceId) =>{
    const docRef = await db
    .collection('customers')
    .doc(user.uid)
    .collection('checkout_sessions')
    .add({
        price:priceId,
        success_url:window.location.origin,
        cancel_url: window.location.origin,
    })
    docRef.onSnapshot(async (snap) =>{
        const {error, sessionId} = snap.data();
        if(error){
            alert(`an error occured ${error.message}`)
        }
        if(sessionId){
            const stripe = await loadStripe("pk_test_51JG0BKLXYmn2IpSgISeCDbsCNllISGA3PvEbSzBz5bpo8WTvmqI6UKCbzpxX92LKiN0hftRrobm1J6wJZPCOWSTs0081pmQFJE")
            const deleted = await stripe.subscriptions.del(
                subscription.id
              );
              console.log(deleted)
            stripe.redirectToCheckout({sessionId});
        }
    })
    
}
```

my code give an error saying stripe.subscriptions.del is not a function.
the code work if I remove this line the payment is successful and all.
In stripe API Docs its says to use .del() but it isnt working here.

Comment: how are you handling changing the subscription? I'm looking at the docs and it seems like updating the subscript and canceling the old one should be done with update? 
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrade-downgrade#changing

According to this:
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/cancel
cancellation should take effect immediately so you shouldn't have to manually go in to cancel the old?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your React code uses Stripe.js which is a client-side library. It cannot modify Subscriptions, only secret key API calls can do that which Stripe.js does not use.

You need to make the request to update/delete the Subscription, you need to make the request server-side (in your Firebase app) using the stripe-node library and your secret API key: https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/cancel?lang=node.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "customer portal" option inside Stripe to avoid backend coding.

It will generate a link to a page where your customer will be able to cancel the subscription.

Inside Stripe: Billing -> subscriptions -> Setup Customer portal